# SSIM index in Mathematica

Tags: image-processing

I was wondering, how one could compute the SSIM index in Mma ? The The structural SIMilarity (SSIM) index, which is a known method for measuring the similarity between two images.

Here is the original paper: http://www.cns.nyu.edu/pub/eero/wang03-reprint.pdf

And this is a nice summary of the essential formula: http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/ssim.html

The SSIM is an index measuring the structural similarity between two images. It is valued between -1 and 1. When two images are nearly identical, their SSIM is close to 1.

Formula computing the SSIM between two sequences seq1 and seq2 at a given pixel P:

$SSIM(P)= \frac{2*\mu_1(P)*\mu_2(P) + C1}{\mu_1(P)^2 + \mu_2(P)^2 + C1} * \frac{2*cov(P) + C2}{s1(P)^2 + s2(P)^2 + C2}$

With:

mu1(P) and mu2(P): mean value of seq1 and seq2 computed over a small XY window located around P

s1(P) and s2(P): standard deviation of seq1 and seq2 computed over the same window

cov(P): covariance between seq1 and seq2 computed over the same window

C1 = (K1*L)^2: regularization constant (should be as small as possible)

C2 = (K2*L)^2: regularization constant (should be as small as possible)

K1, K2: regularization parameters (must be >0)

L: dynamic range of the pixel values (example: L=255 if the sequence is 8 bit encoded)

Comment: There's MATLAB code [here](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/ssim/ssim_index.m) from the authors, so this amounts to a tedious translation job...

Comment: And here is the Python code ... https://github.com/jterrace/pyssim/tree/master/ssim

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Attempt to reconstruct the original author's stuff

I was curious enough to have a look into the Matlab source code [ssim.m](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/ssim/ssim.m) provided by the original authors [Wang et al. 2004](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIP.2003.819861). I have tried my best to exactly re-implement this code with Wolfram Language using MMA 9 (have checked it under MMA 11.3 as well and have re-arrangend the listing below for better readability):

```
MyMSSIM[
   img1raw_Image,
   img2raw_Image,
   window_: GaussianMatrix[{Table[(11 - 1)/2, {2}], 1.5}, 
     Method -> "Gaussian"],
   k1_: 0.01, k2_: 0.03] :=
  Module[{
    f = Max[1, Round[Min[Sequence @@ ImageDimensions[img1raw]]/256]],
    img1in = ColorConvert[Image[img1raw, "Real"], "Grayscale"],
    img2in = ColorConvert[Image[img2raw, "Real"], "Grayscale"],
    mssimmap, mssim},

   If[f > 1,(*if subsampling needs to be done*)
    {img1in, img2in} =
     ImageCorrelate[
        ImagePad[#,(*to mimic the Matlab imfilter edge treatment*)
         NestList[Reverse, {Floor[(f - 1)/2], Ceiling[(f - 1)/2]}, 1],
         "Reversed"],
        ConstantArray[1./Times[f, f], {f, f}],
        Padding -> None] & /@ {img1in, img2in};
    {img1in, img2in} = 
     ImageTake[#, {1, -1, f}, {1, -1, f}] & /@ {img1in, img2in};
    ];

   mssimmap =
    Function[{img1, img2},
      Function[{mu1, mu2},
        Function[{mu1mu1, mu2mu2, mu1mu2},
          ImageApply[#1/#2 &,
           {ImageMultiply[
             ImageAdd[
              ImageMultiply[mu1mu2, 2.],
              k1^2],
             ImageAdd[
              ImageMultiply[
               ImageSubtract[
                ImageCorrelate[
                 ImageMultiply[img1, img2],
                 window, Padding -> None],
                mu1mu2],
               2.],
              k2^2]
             ],
            ImageMultiply[
             ImageAdd[
              ImageAdd[mu1mu1, mu2mu2],
              k1^2],
             ImageAdd[
              ImageAdd[
               ImageSubtract[
                ImageCorrelate[
                 ImageMultiply[img1, img1],
                 window, Padding -> None],
                mu1mu1],
               ImageSubtract[
                ImageCorrelate[
                 ImageMultiply[img2, img2],
                 window, Padding -> None],
                mu2mu2]],
              k2^2]
             ]
            }
           ]
          ][
         ImageMultiply[mu1, mu1],
         ImageMultiply[mu2, mu2],
         ImageMultiply[mu1, mu2]
         ]
        ][
       ImageCorrelate[img1, window, Padding -> None],
       ImageCorrelate[img2, window, Padding -> None]
       ]
      ][img1in, img2in
     ];
   mssim = ImageMeasurements[mssimmap, "Mean"];
   Return@mssim;
   ];
```

I more or less consequently was using the built-in routines to handle `Image` data.

I have checked the examples given under [http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/ssim](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/ssim/#test):

```
urlbase = "http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/ssim/";
imagelist = {"einstein.gif", "meanshift.gif", "contrast.gif", "impulse.gif", "blur.gif", "jpg.gif"};
Function[{name1, name2}, 
    Column[{Last@StringSplit[name2, "/"], Show@#2, 
        "Mean SSIM: " <> ToString@MyMSSIM[#1, #2]}, Center] &[
     Import@name1, Import@name2]][urlbase <> First@imagelist, 
   urlbase <> #] & /@ imagelist
```

Please re-check and compare by your own. I also compared a plenty of mean SSIM values for image pairs one-by-one with the output of the Matlab code and found no differences within the precision of the displayed mantissa.

What I skipped in the original Matlab code was any check of minimum image sizes and something like that, and I also did not cover the unlikely case that someone will operate with either `k1` or `k2` set to `0`. Their presets (0.01 and 0.03, resp.) as well as parameters for the Gaussian smoothing kernel `window` were also taken from that code. As you can see in my code, I also mimic the strange smoothing using a box filter in case of a sub-sampling of images larger than 383 pixels at their short edge. And I generally did exactly the same edge handling using certain `Padding` settings.

Please look at two basic examples (part of Wang's demo as the other examples given above):

```
MyMSSIM[Import@"http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/ssim/einstein.gif", 
 Import@"http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/ssim/meanshift.gif"]
```

gives

```
0.988359
```

for [image: einstein.gif] and [image: meanshift.gif]

while

```
MyMSSIM[Import@"http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/ssim/einstein.gif", 
 Import@"http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/ssim/jpg.gif"]
```

gives

```
0.662363
```

for [image: einstein.gif] and [image: enter code here]

There is a very small change I made, as the original Matlab code is intended for scalar images and cannot handle RGB images, in case someone inserts RGB images here, I convert them to real valued luminance images. As values now are in the interval [0.,1.], I could cancel the parameter L in the original code, indicating the maximum pixel value. BTW, output range is between -1 and 1, while for typical image pairs the result will be positive.

What I did not consider so far was any multi-scale implementation of the Structural SIMilarity (SSIM), called MS-SSIM [msssim.m](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~z70wang/research/ssim/msssim.zip)

Comment: Wow ! This is great !! Thank you for that answer !

Comment: My main focus was to stay as close as possible to the original author, but to be honest, I do not really understand so far why they have used a subsampling for images exceeding certain sizes. What I observed is that the resulting SSIM considerably can decrease if no subsampling is being done. Basically, @CalAster has implemented to full essence of the algorithm in his update (his code requires MMA 11, I think, mine works with MMA 9 as I need to teach using this version).

Answer (score 6):

I just translate the formula:

$$\begin{aligned}
L(X,Y) &= \frac{2u_Xu_Y + C_1}{{u_X}^2+{u_Y}^2+C_1}\\
C(X,Y) &= \frac{2\sigma_X\sigma_Y+C_2}{{\sigma_X}^2+{\sigma_Y}^2 + C_2}\\
S(X,Y) &= \frac{\sigma_{XY} + C_3}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y + C_3}
\end{aligned}$$

$$\mathrm{SSIM}= L(X,Y)^\alpha ×C(X,Y)^\beta ×S(X,Y)^\gamma$$

Where:

$$\begin{cases}
C_1=(K_1\cdot L)^2, C_2=(K_2\cdot L)^2, C_3=C_2/2\\
K_1=0.01, K_2=0.03, L=255\\
\alpha =\beta =\gamma=1
\end{cases}$$

So we get:

$$\hbox{SSIM}(X,Y)={\frac{(2\mu_x\mu _{y}+C_{1})(2\sigma _{xy}+C_2)}{({\mu_x}^2+{\mu _y}^2+C_1)({\sigma_x}^2+{\sigma_y}^2+C_2)}}$$

```
MSSIM[img1_Image, img2_Image, n_Integer] := SSIM @@ Transpose[ImagePartition[#, Scaled[1 / n]]& /@ {img1, img2}] / n^2;
SSIM[img1_Image, img2_Image] := Module[
    {i1, i2, mx, my, vx, vy, c1, c2, cov},
    i1 = N@Flatten@ImageData[img1, "Byte"];
    i2 = N@Flatten@ImageData[img2, "Byte"];
    {mx, my} = Mean /@ {i1, i2};
    {vx, vy} = StandardDeviation /@ {i1, i2};
    {c1, c2} = {255 * 0.01, 255 * 0.03}^2;
    cov = Covariance[i1, i2];
    (2mx * my + c1)(2cov + c2) / (mx^2 + my^2 + c1) / (vx^2 + vy^2 + c2)
]
```

But there's something wrong, it not match the original answer.

http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/ssim/#test

```
img1=Import["http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/ssim/einstein.gif"];
img2=Import["http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/ssim/meanshift.gif"];
SSIM[img1,img2]
```

It should be 0.988 but I got 0.997 and I can't figure out what's wrong.

---

### Update:

@UDB gave the right answer, so I have to correct my code.

```
Options[SSIM] = {
    "C1" -> 0.01^2, "C2" -> 0.03^2,
    "Window" -> GaussianMatrix[{{(11 - 1) / 2, (11 - 1) / 2}, 1.5}, Method -> "Gaussian"]
};
SSIM[img1_Image, img2_Image, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
    {c1, c2, window, mx, my, vx, vy, cov, r},
    {c1, c2, window} = OptionValue[{"C1", "C2", "Window"}];
    mx = ImageCorrelate[img1, window, Padding -> None];
    my = ImageCorrelate[img2, window, Padding -> None];
    vx = ImageCorrelate[img1^2, window, Padding -> None] - mx^2;
    vy = ImageCorrelate[img2^2, window, Padding -> None] - my^2;
    cov = ImageCorrelate[img1 * img2, window, Padding -> None] - mx * my;
    r = (2mx * my + c1) / (mx^2 + my^2 + c1) * (2cov + c2) / (vx + vy + c2);
    Mean@ImageMeasurements[r, "Mean"]
]
```

The sixth place after the decimal point is a little different.

I don't know if `ImageCorrelate` is an efficient function, and I am glad to see some more efficient code.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer ! I can't find the error either. Do you think, that you could open a new question to find the source of the error and then post the answer, if there is one, here ?

Comment: @GalAsterThere is no better way to do correlations or convolutions on images as to use `ImageCorrelate` or `ImageConvolve`.